# creating interactive charts using laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, charts

Please Help me i need pass this sql lines to a laravel syxtax to use
on customizable charts
Im using 
https://github.com/ConsoleTVs/Charts
Sql Syntax:

```
    SELECT 
 SUM(CASE WHEN status like 'Por Despachar' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Por_Despachar
,SUM(CASE WHEN status like 'Planificado' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Planificado
,SUM(CASE WHEN status like 'Despachado' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Despachado
    FROM presupuesto
```

i want to add this parameter on interactive chart like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pl3ra.png)

This is my Controller:

```html
<?php

namespace sisVentas\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use sisVentas\User;
use sisVentas\Http\Requests;
use Charts;
class EstadisticaController extends Controller
{
    //

public function index()
    {
    $data = \DB::select("
            SELECT 
                SUM(CASE WHEN status like 'Por Despachar' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Por_Despachar
                ,SUM(CASE WHEN status like 'Planificado' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Planificado
                ,SUM(CASE WHEN status like 'Despachado' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Despachado
            FROM presupuesto
        ");





        $chart =  Charts::create('pie', 'highcharts')
            // Setup the chart settings
            ->title("Resumen de Presupuestos Realizados")
            // A dimension of 0 means it will take 100% of the space
            // This defines a preset of colors already done:)

            // You could always set them manually

            // Setup the diferent datasets (this is a multi chart)
  ->labels(['Por Despachar', 'Despachado', 'Planificado'])
  ->values([65,10,20])
  ->dimensions(1000,500)
  ->responsive(false);
        return dd($chart, $data);

    }

}
```

```css
Chart {#324 ▼
  +id: null
  +customId: null
  +type: "pie"
  +library: "highcharts"
  +title: "Resumen de Presupuestos Realizados"
  +element_label: "Element"
  +labels: array:3 [▼
    0 => "Por Despachar"
    1 => "Despachado"
    2 => "Planificado"
  ]
  +values: array:3 [▼
    0 => 65
    1 => 10
    2 => 20
  ]
  +colors: []
  +responsive: false
  +gauge_style: "left"
  +view: null
  +region: "world"
  #suffix: ""
  +container: ""
  +credits: false
  +loader: true
  +loader_duration: 500
  +loader_color: "#000000"
  +background_color: "inherit"
  +template: "material"
  +one_color: false
  +legend: true
  +x_axis_title: false
  +y_axis_title: null
  +"height": 500
  +"width": 1000
}

array:1 [▼
  0 => {#330 ▼
    +"por_despachar": "3"
    +"planificado": "1"
    +"despachado": "0"
  }
]
```

Comment: Do you want to replace `->values([5,10,20])` with your SQL result? I dont understand your language to make some assumptions on your code

Comment: yes bro i want to replace with my sql result

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not direct answer but should be helpful

When you have any SQL query that is hard / impossible to convert into eloquent, just use DB facade.

```
$data = \DB::select("
            SELECT 
                SUM(CASE WHEN status like 'Por Despachar' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Por_Despachar
                ,SUM(CASE WHEN status like 'Planificado' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Planificado
                ,SUM(CASE WHEN status like 'Despachado' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Despachado
            FROM presupuesto
        ");

dd($data);
```

Comment: thanks bro im getting the right values perfectly. can you help me pass these results to the chart

Comment: It should be either `->values($data)` or `->values($data->toArray())`

Comment: With this ->values($data->toArray()) i get this error "Call to a member function toArray() on array" and with this ->values($data) Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception

Comment: The second solution should be the correct one then, because your errors probably came from blade view. Can you `dd($chart)` ?

Comment: Thanks for reply, i update the description check please

Comment: Will you get correct html by calling `{!! $chart->render() !!}` in your blade view? Ofc you need to pass $chart variable to returning view

Comment: yes bro the problem is when im trying to put the values here ->values([5,10,20])

Answer (score 0):

```php
$chart = Charts::database($data, 'pie', 'highcharts')              
        ->title('Amount subscribers')        
        ->labels([Por_Despachar, Planificado, Despachado])                            
        ->values([$data[0]->Por_Despachar, $data[1]->Planificado, $data[2]->Despachado])
        ->dimensions(1000,500)
        ->responsive(true);
```